# Change range of colors in an image using python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on automating changing image colors using python. The image I'm using is below, i'd love to move it from red to another range of colors, say green, keeping the detail and shading if possible. I've been able to convert *some* of the image to a solid color, losing all detail.

[image: Blue instead of red.]

The code I'm currently using is below, I can't quite figure out the correct range of red to make it work correctly, and also it only converts to a single color, again losing all detail and shade.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# load image and get dimensions
img = cv2.imread("test5.jpg")

# convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

## mask of upper red (170,50,50) ~ (180,255,255)
## mask of lower red (0,50,50) ~ (10,255,255)
# threshold using inRange
range1 = (0,50,50)
range2 = (1,255,255)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,range1,range2)
mask = 255 - mask

# apply morphology opening to mask
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# antialias mask
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (0,0), sigmaX=3, sigmaY=3, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(mask, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255))

result = img.copy()
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("test6.jpg", result)
```

Comment: You need two sets of red colors one range of red colors for hues below 180 (say 170 to 180) for low and high and another set of red colors for hues above 180 (say 0 to 10) since red spans the 180 and 0 transition in OpenCV Hue. Both will map to your new color. Then you need to combine the two threshold results for your mask.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to approach the problem in Python/OpenCV. But for red, it is very hard to do because red spans 0 hue, which also is the hue for gray and white and black, which you have in your image. The other issue you have is that skin tones has red shades, so you cannot pick too large of ranges for your colors. Also when dealing with red ranges, you need two sets, one for hues up to 180 and another for hues above 0.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('red_clothes.jpg')

# convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)

blue_hue = 120
red_hue = 0

# diff hue (blue_hue - red_hue)
diff_hue = blue_hue - red_hue

# create mask for red color in hsv
lower1 = (150,150,150)
upper1 = (180,255,255)
mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower1, upper1)
lower2 = (0,150,150)
upper2 = (30,255,255)
mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower2, upper2)
mask = cv2.add(mask1,mask2)
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# apply morphology to clean mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# modify hue channel by adding difference and modulo 180 
hnew = np.mod(h + diff_hue, 180).astype(np.uint8)

# recombine channels
hsv_new = cv2.merge([hnew,s,v])

# convert back to bgr
bgr_new = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_new, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# blend with original using mask
result = np.where(mask==(255, 255, 255), bgr_new, img)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('red_clothes_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('red_clothes_hue_shift.png', bgr_new)
cv2.imwrite('red_clothes_red2blue.png', result)

# Display various images to see the steps
cv2.imshow('mask1',mask1)
cv2.imshow('mask2',mask2)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('bgr_new',bgr_new)
cv2.imshow('result',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask:

[image]

Hue Shifted Image:

[image]

Blend between Input and Hue Shifted Image using Mask to blend:

[image]

So the result is speckled because of the black mixed with the red and from limited ranges due to skin color.

Comment: Hello @fmw42. I think changing hue like this is a bit softer --> h, s, v = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(im.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
    h[np.where(msk == 0)] = hue
    cv2.cvtColor(cv2.merge([h, s, v]), cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

Comment: I mean, maybe this solution could be used instead of **diff_hue** :)

Comment: the blue with green speckles are odd. the +180 calculation might overflow because it's uint8.

Comment: red is a no go, right. I'll amend the original image to be blue and work off of that.

Comment: Yes and No. You can use a trick of inverting the image so that red becomes cyan. This improves the result, though not completely changeable due to skin tones being close to red. See my answer above. Then see my answer starting with your blue clothes. Changing to red is much more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with red, but the trick is to invert the image so red is now at hue 90 in OpenCV range and for example blue is at hue 30. So in Python/OpenCV, you can do the following:

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('red_clothes.jpg')

# invert image
imginv = 255 - img

# convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(imginv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)

blueinv_hue = 30  #(=120+180/2=210-180=30)
redinv_hue = 90  #(=0+180/2=90)

# diff hue (blue_hue - red_hue)
diff_hue = blueinv_hue - redinv_hue

# create mask for redinv color in hsv
lower = (80,150,150)
upper = (100,255,255)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# apply morphology to clean mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# modify hue channel by adding difference and modulo 180 
hnew = np.mod(h + diff_hue, 180).astype(np.uint8)

# recombine channels
hsv_new = cv2.merge([hnew,s,v])

# convert back to bgr
bgrinv_new = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_new, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# invert
bgr_new = 255 -bgrinv_new

# blend with original using mask
result = np.where(mask==(255, 255, 255), bgr_new, img)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('red_clothes_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('red_clothes_hue_shift.png', bgr_new)
cv2.imwrite('red_clothes_red2blue.png', result)

# Display various images to see the steps
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('bgr_new',bgr_new)
cv2.imshow('result',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask:

[image]

Red to Blue before masking:

[image]

Red to Blue after masking:

[image]

However, one is still limited by the fact that red is close to skin tones, so the range for red is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a blue image rather than red allows one to use an expanded range for inRange() and do a better job in Python/OpenCV. Here is a change from blue to red.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('blue_clothes.jpg')

# convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)

red_hue = 0
blue_hue = 120

# diff hue (red_hue - blue_hue)
diff_hue = red_hue - blue_hue

# create mask for blue color in hsv
lower = (100,90,90)
upper = (140,255,255)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# apply morphology to clean mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# modify hue channel by adding difference and modulo 180 
hnew = np.mod(h + diff_hue, 180).astype(np.uint8)

# recombine channels
hsv_new = cv2.merge([hnew,s,v])

# convert back to bgr
bgr_new = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_new, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# blend with original using mask
result = np.where(mask==(255, 255, 255), bgr_new, img)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('blue_clothes_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('blue_clothes_hue_shift.png', bgr_new)
cv2.imwrite('blue_clothes_blue2red.png', result)

# Display various images to see the steps
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('bgr_new',bgr_new)
cv2.imshow('result',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask:

[image]

Blue to Red before masking:

[image]

Blue to Red after masking:

[image]

Comment: nice, that's damn close, great job.

Comment: This idea is great